# Listener from pynput blocks functions inside on_press until it ends running

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I am trying to write an interactive command line program using input keys to print specific text to the terminal, and it has the following structure:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

def choix_case(tour='X'):

    variable = 1
    def goto_case(a):
        print ('\033[u', end='') #Escape code to reset the cursor position
        print ('\033[', a*2, 'B', sep='', end='') #Escape code to move [a] times to the right
    def print_choice():
        #Some escape codes to change the style of the next printed text:
        blinking('on')
        bg_color()
        fg_color(0xd7,0x5f,0x5f)
        print('X', end='') #The actual printed text
        #Escape code to reset the style:
        blinking('off')
        fg_color()
        bg_color()

    goto_case(variable)
    print_choice()

    def on_press(key):
        nonlocal variable
        if key == Key.right:
             variable+=1
        if key == Key.enter:
            return False
        goto_case(variable)
        print_choice()
    with Listener(on_press = on_press) as clef:
        clef.join()
```

It is supposed to execute the goto_case and print_choice functions each time a key is pressed, and then close the Listener when Enter key is pressed.
Basically, it prints an 'X', and adds another 'X' on the next position each time I press the Right key, but it prints nothing, and then prints them all at once (for example 'X X X' for 3 times) after I press enter.

The problem is that nothing is printed until the Enter key is pressed, and then everything is printed at once. It's as if the Listener saved all the times on_press() ran, and then released them once it closed.

And what is even weirder is that if I printed a '\n' at any point inside the on_press() function ( or inside goto_case or print_choice which are called inside on_press, or I remove the end='' option from any print), it prints what happens each time I press a key. So the problem seems to be in the fact that there is no newline char printed? Why would that block the printing while the Listener is still running?

Comment: Can you provide the actual code for `goto_case` and `print_choice`? How / Why do you call `goto_case` with 1 and 2 arguments? I don't see where `variable` is defined outside `on_press`, so how can you mark it as `nonlocal`?

Comment: @blueteeth Sorry, tried to simplify the code to only focus on the problem but I removed too much. (the goto_case function moves the cursor on two dimensions depending on two parameters following the L/R/U/D arrows keys but I simplified it to only one parameter)
I edited the post with the code of the two functions and corrected the argument errors, I hope it's a little bit clearer

Comment: In `goto_case` when you call `print` it should be used as a function with one main argument `print(f'\033[{a*2}B', sep='', end='')`. Note the lack of space after the keyword, and the single string. Not sure that's the issue, but something to note.